# Find duplicated word in string and in which two positions it appears

Tags: python

I am fighting a bit with this problem. I want to write a code, which will find a duplicate word in a string from an input and print that word. Along with the word I also want to print the word positions in the given string.

This is my code so far, but on the output I still get the word repeated. Any ideas how to fix it?

**Input:** `juice bread tea water apple tea carrot coconut`

**Output - desired:** `tea 1 4`

```
string = str(input())

string_list = string.split(' ')

for j in range(len(string_list)):
    duplicate = string_list.count(string_list[j])

    if duplicate > 1: 
        
        print((string_list[j]), (j), end=' ')
```

**Output - current:** `tea 2 tea 5`

Comment: Have you considered saving the results then printing them after the loop? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: Sidenotes: 1) `str(input())` is redundant since `input()` returns `str`. 2) The parentheses are redundant on `(string_list[j]), (j)`. 3) In general, avoid `for i in range(len(x)): ... i, x[i]`. Instead use `for i, v in enumerate(x): ... i, v`. It's more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = str(input())

string_list = string.split(' ')
duplicates = [word for word in string_list if string_list.count(word) > 1]
unique_duplicates = list(set(duplicates))

occurences = list()
for index, elem in enumerate(string_list):
    if elem == unique_duplicates[0]:
        occurences.append(index)

print(f"{unique_duplicates[0]} {occurences[0]} {occurences[1]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a code, which will find a duplicate word in a string from an input and print that word. Along with the word I also want to print the word positions in the given string.

Try the below

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
_input = 'juice bread tea water apple tea carrot coconut'
words = _input.split(' ')
for idx, word in enumerate(words):
    data[word].append(idx)
for word, index_list in data.items():
    if len(index_list) > 1:
        print(f'{word} -> {index_list}')
```

output

```
tea -> [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's always exactly one duplicated word, you can simply break the loop when you find it, then get the index of its next occurrence in the list.

```
def find_duplicate_word(string):
    words = string.split(' ')
    for first_occ, word in enumerate(words):
        if words.count(word) > 1:
            break
    second_occ = words.index(word, first_occ+1)
    return word, first_occ, second_occ

result = find_duplicate_word('juice bread tea water apple tea carrot coconut')
print(*result)  # -> tea 2 5
```

---

Note that `words.count()` has to do a search on every loop, which is fine for small inputs, but for bigger inputs, I'd use something more like [balderman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74174195/4518341), with `defaultdict(list)`. That would bring the solution from *O(n^2)* to *O(n)*. Plus it'd work if the number of duplicates is not always one.

Answer (score 0):

the task can be done also in this way:

```
txt = 'bread tea water apple tea carrot coconut juice'.split()
seen = []
for word in txt:
    if txt.count(word) > 1 and word not in seen:
        print(word, *[ind for ind, i in enumerate(txt) if i == word])
        seen.append(word)
```